# How to query stories for type="comment"

Tags: asana

I'm new to REST and the Asana API so forgive me for asking what could be a very basic question!

I am basically trying to get a list of all the Comments for a particular task.

I have tried using \stories?type="comment" but this does not seem to work and returns all the story items, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: looking at the docs - http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#stories this doesn't look possible? Doesn't look like this functionality is implemented their side?

Comment: I was fearing that @Alex. I must admit I am a little confused by it though since the documentation does list the type: as read only. Since it states it I would have presumed I would have been able to query that field. Hey ho, getting to grips with REST is a steep learning curve coming from WinForms! LOL!

Comment: "read only" means that you can see that field but can't modify it via the API, not necessarily that you can *query* by it.

Comment: @agnoster, thanks for clearing my confusion up! Would it be possible for you guys to update the documentation to state which fields are queryable, maybe another tag next to each property #queryable or something? It would certainly help newbies such as myself!

Comment: We document the acceptable query parameters in the documentation of the query method. Take a look at, for example, the "Querying for Tasks" section - each query param is documented there. I think the issue is that you're conflating model properties with query parameters - the two are not, generally speaking, interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can't filter this via the API and need to filter on the client side. We're working on a new, more powerful querying feature, but a) this is still early in the design phase and b) it will probably come to tasks first.

In general, we prioritize the things that currently can't be done via the API over the things that can be done, but require a little work on the client side. If someone wants to search a whole workspace for tasks that match a given query, that's something you can't really do at all via the API, so we'd see that as higher priority than something like this, where it's comparatively easy to filter down to only comments on the client. That's not to say we don't *care* about those features, and we'd like to do them all, but we only have so many hours in the day so we have to prioritize.

Comment: Ok well that does help, I landed up doing that but I wanted to make sure I wasn't being dense and missing a trick or misunderstanding the API somehow.